# npm install error EACCES permission denied?

Tags: npm, installation

I have permission problem using npm.
When I write "npm install"

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/ItsMe'
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at errorHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:211:17)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:83:20
    at cb (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:215:22)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:253:24
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:81:7
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:80:13
    at f (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/once/once.js:25:25)
    at afterExtras (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:178:20)
    at Conf.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:235:20)
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:211
  if (npm.config.get('json')) {
                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at process.errorHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:211:17)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at process.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at process._fatalException (bootstrap_node.js:304:26)
```

With a "ls -l" I have rwx rights.
I don't understand what "Cannot read property 'get' of undefined" means.

I searched on the web and tried several things but it' doesn't work.
Could you help me ?

Thank you

Comment: `sudo npm install` ?

Comment: Thanks. An additional question:  don't understand wekll the use of npm install with nothing after install (I mean not npm install package) I've read this but I'm still confused https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install. Does it create node-modules architecture only ? What does npm loads if I do not precise which package I want to use ?

Comment: @droledenom You need to specify a package name, for example - "npm install -g PACKAGE-NAME"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `npm install` try to do an mkdir in a file you don't have access to. Try to give him the right by doing

```
sudo npm install
```

or doing it as a super user (I dont recomand that) You also asked what `npm install` do without argument. Well if ou don't specify a folder it creates the folder `node_module` (that is why it does an mkdir). If you don't precise a module it will install all the module from `package.json`. It can take morte time and you will have a lots of package you won't need but with that you will be sure to have the one you want.

You can choose the package you want if you exactly know wich one. ie :

```
npm install sax@latest
```

the `latest` mean it gonna search for the last existing package

ANd you can also install a package you downloaded yourself. ie :

```
npm install ./package.tgz
```